# How do I export contents between xml tags based on names in Extendscript for Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

All I'd like to do here is open an InDesign 2018 CC file, pull out text uniquely (here I've chosen to grab content inside XML tag called "Title" from named tag window in the InDesign application side), save it to a txt file, and close the InDesign doc. I'm working in the Extendscript app, using Adobe InDesign CC 2018 (13.064). I just need to push to a txt file only certain named data (textboxes, xmltags, pageitems, etc) the contents based on anything, but via the name of the data holder. But xmltags are the only objects that I can name in the InDesign app apart from layers, and layers won't work for other reasons. So I'm stuck not being able to refer to xml-tagged contents. Please help.

Note:

1. I get an error with this code saying "Title" isn't defined, and I understand the error, but not sure how to utilize the method XML.toString() without referring to an object that's named inside the InDesign file. So I guess I'm using the wrong method to refer to xml-tagged data already located in a file??
2. So naturally, I throw out XML.toString() and utilize the commented out code (below) "app.activeDocument.xmlItems.item;" thinking maybe I will get an array of all items that are xml tagged, which is not even specific enough for my goal, but I'm desperate, and I get another newer error regarding the "exportfile" line of code: myArticles.exportFile() is not a function.

My code so far:

```
app.open(File("C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/New folder/va tech 2.indd"), true);
myArticles = Title.toString();
//THIS ATTEMPT WON'T WORK EITHER AS RPLCMNT FOR LINE ABOVE: myArticles= app.activeDocument.xmlItems.item;  
myArticles.exportFile(ExportFormat.textType, new File("/C/Users/Sean/Desktop/New folder/test.txt"), false);
app.documents.everyItem().close(SaveOptions.NO);
```

Comment: [This](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2499620) may be of use, particularly `Guild - Office Pro`'s answer (third from the bottom)

Comment: What is `Title`? Can you give a little more code context?

Comment: Thank you, Josh. "Title" merely refers to one of the names of the Tags (Tag window inside InDesign CC) to which I'm trying to refer. There's also another one called "abstract." And will probably have another one called "authors." And so I mean to export this data to txt. After I can export the contents of these Tags from 1 InDesign file, then I will apply the code to multiple InDesign files. But first I have to export 1 file's data.

Comment: Think: how would the Javascript compiler "know" that `Title` is an XML tag and not a variable (which is probably how it currently interprets it in your code). Did you check out the link I provided? You may also want ot read up on the InDesign object model. Adobe has some decent [documentation](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) and [this](http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html) is another great online resource.

Comment: Thank you, cybernetic.nomad. I accidentally skipped past chapter 12 in the scripting guide referring to XML paths.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var main = function() {
 
 var doc, root, xes, n, nXE, st, xc, strs = [],
 f = File ( Folder.desktop+"/contents.txt" );
 
 try {
  
  //NEED TO CHANGE THE URL. Ex:  some/url > /Users/user/Desktop/foo.indd
  doc = app.open ( File ( "some/url" ) );
 }
 catch(err){
   alert(err.message);
   return;
 }

 if ( !doc ) {
  alert("You need an open document" );
  return;
 }
 
 root = doc.xmlElements[0];
 xes = root.evaluateXPathExpression("//Title");
 n = xes.length;
 while ( n-- ) {
  nXE = xes[n];
  xc = nXE.xmlContent;
  if ( xc instanceof Story ) {
   strs.push( xc.contents );
  }
 }
 if ( strs.length ) {
  f.open('w');
  f.write ( strs.reverse().join("\r") );
  f.close();
 }
 
}

var u;

app.doScript ( "main()",u,u,UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "The Script" );
```